# Moving app when keyboard is displayed in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I would like "scroll" my app if keyboard is open. My problem is i don't have ScrollView component, it's form with plain page without Scroll because my app can't scroll on vertical.

So, if i open my keyboard, the field is hidden by iOS keyboard.

I've test more module, but it work with ScrollView :(

Anyone have idea ?

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580

Comment: Give my answer a go down below. It solved the problem for us where i work

Answer (score 0):

If you need your screen to scroll when the keyboard is open you can try a npm module called react-native-input-scroll-view:

https://github.com/baijunjie/react-native-input-scroll-view

This will re-adjust your screen with your keyboard appropriately. You can wrap your form in this and you should be good to go. 
We had this problem before and react-native components that are meant to fix the issue did not help.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have the view move when the keyboard shows up

Change your `<View>` to a `<KeyboardAvoidignView>`

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={styles.container}
  behavior="padding"
>
```

Comment: Hi :) it add only padding, but no scroll in my case.

Comment: Okay, you can also try `height` or `position` for the behavior prop.  I'm guessing position is the answer.